# Remove Resource id # from curl post for database

Tags: php, mysql, curl

What i am trying to achieve here is to test if a website is online and then post it into a database

The following code works apart from the column **curl** as it input Resource id #2
if the site is down and Resource id #1 if the site is up

```
   <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $url = $_POST['url'];
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_exec($curl);
            $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if ($code == 200) {
                echo "<h3>Up!</h3>";
            } else {
                echo "<h3> $curl!</h3>";
            }
        }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'root';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO site".
           "(url, curl) ".
           "VALUES('$url','$curl')";
    mysql_select_db('up');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //end
    echo "fuck it";
    mysql_close($conn);
    }
    else
    {

    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        Url: <input type="text" name="url" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
<?php
        }
        ?>
```

There might be some security issues with this code but all i am trying to learn here is to get this to work then ill worry about the security as that is new to myself

The format in which I am trying to store the data is 1 if on-line and 2 if offline

my table is as follows

```
id       | url       | curl       |
```

Comment: `$curl` is a resource. What are you trying to store to database? Shouldn't it be `$code`?

Comment: a value ie if Resource id #2 = to remove the "Resource id #" part so i am left with a 2

Comment: In general it would be tough to predict what resource number php is going to assign to a resource (and may change in the future), so you shouldn't rely on that to determine what you want to insert into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1 is supposed to be online a 2 offline, then

```
$result = $code == 200 ? 1 : 2;
```

and then

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO site(url, curl) VALUES('$url','$result')";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if ($code == 200) {
    $curl_value = 1;
} else {
    $curl_value = 0;
}
```

Then insert `$curl_value` instead of the curl resource.